# How to handle keyboard events in a  winapi standard dialog?

Tags: c++, winforms, winapi, keyboard, callback

i don't often work with winapi, i'm writing almost .NET code. But at this time I have to use the winapi to make a simple dialog. There i want to handle some keyevents. Therefore i watched for the corresponding callback message [`WM_KEYDOWN` or `WM_KEYUP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280%28VS.85%29.aspx) at MSDN and added it to my callback function.

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK cbfunc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
  switch(message) {
    // ...

    case WM_KEYUP:
        MMsgBox("up"); // I never get here
        return 0;

    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        MMsgBox("down"); // I never get here        
        return 0;

    // ...
  }
  return 0;
}
```

But neither `WM_KEYUP` nor `WM_KEYDOWN` ever get triggered. Then I stated looking for a solution for this problem. I thought may my dialog eats this messages. So I added:

```
    case WM_GETDLGCODE: 
        return DLGC_WANTALLKEYS;
```

With the result that it doesn't help.
Other solutions I've found were the following:

- Alternatively using the `WM_GETDLGCODE` event to handle this keys as suggested on [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/community/history/ms646280%28v=VS.85%29.aspx?id=4).
- I've found a lot of threads (like [this one](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/35982805/pretranslatemessage.aspx)) talking about a method called `PreTranslateMessage`. But I don't even have got this class, because I simply create my dialog by using [`DialogBoxParam`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

So none of them worked for me. In the moment i have got no idea how to handle it. Something I've noticed, is that on key press a `WM_COMMAND` message seems to occur.

Regards Nem.

Comment: What does your message handler look like? I just tried this and it worked fine for me (message boxes pop up).

Comment: Even if i comment out everything else nothing happens. So it looks like posted above.

Comment: No, I mean your `while` and `GetMessage` stuff. Sorry, guess I should have said "message loop."

Comment: There is none, I think it is handled by DialogBoxParam.

Comment: Oh, didn't see that. Have you read this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/117563

Comment: I don't derive from anything like CWinApp. This is a simple call and a resource. 
DialogBoxParam(hInstance, 
  MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOGRESOURCE), 
  hParent, dialogProc, (LPARAM)this);

Comment: According to http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/windows/225781/225781/wm_keydown-never-happens-in-dialog/, it has to be done using a custom dialog box. Unless you want to use [`GetAsyncKeyState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I guess I'll put that into an answer then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/117563), certain messages are hard to trap with dialog boxes because Windows processes them internally and they never get to the `DialogProc`. Here are two of the options I can think of:

1. Use [`GetAsyncKeyState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx) on a `WM_COMMAND` event
2. Create a custom dialog box, the `DialogProc` for which *will* handle `WM_KEYDOWN` etc. messages.

Answer (score 2):

DialogProc doesn't receive WM_KEY events (and many others too). You can:

1. Subclass the dialog window (overwrite its WndProc) and process all
   messages there, [sample](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/257da7cd-09cf-426a-a2bf-007dd2ef97ad/how-to-catch-wmkeydown-in-my-dlgproc-call-back-function?forum=vssmartdevicesnative)
2. Register hot key for the dialog window's HWND and then receive WM_HOTKEY in DlgProc (but registered key combinations will be system-wide)
3. Create your own message loop, [link](http://comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32.narkive.com/A1ZPUkYA/dialog-box-not-receiving-wm-keydown)

Answer (score -1):

Replace This

case WM_KEYUP:
        MMsgBox("up"); // I never get here
        return 0;

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
    MMsgBox("down"); // I never get here        
    return 0;
```

With This

case WM_KEYUP:
        MMsgBox("up"); // I never get here
        break;

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
    MMsgBox("down"); // I never get here        
    break;
```